# Getting System.OverflowException using GroupBy and anonymous class

Tags: c#

There is a custom `class A` with properties `Name` and `Amount`

There is a nested List of iterations of `List A`.

To get each unique `List A` and its total amount, count etc. I use following code:
`

```
public void GetStatistic()
        {
            var result = NestedListofListA.SelectMany(iteration => iteration)
                .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
                .Select(a => new
                {
                    a.Key,
                    Count = a.Count(),
                    Amount = a.Sum(a => a.Amount),
                    Min = a.Min(a => a.Amount),
                    Max = a.Max(a => a.Amount)
                })
                .OrderBy(a => a.key);            
        }
```

`The problem is, if nested list count is over about 3 millions iterations I get

```
System.OverflowException: 'Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.'
```

`Amount`, `Min` and `Max` for sure can't exceed `int.MaxValue` with just 3 million iterations, I'm not sure what causing the problem.

I can workaround the problem by creating a unique list of A from nested list

`var uniqueAList = NestedListofA.SelectMany(list => list).DistinctBy(a => a.Name).ToList();`

and then use nested foreach to get the same statistic but the code is larger and slower

I tried to explicitly convert anonymous class properties to long to be sure the problem is not related to it but it didn't help

**UPDATE:**
With the following fix the code is working:

```
Amount = a.Sum(a => (long)a.Amount)
```

Thanks to user @vivek nuna

Comment: Have you tried checking the generated query? Just comment the Sum line. And try. I think it’s exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check the generated query. In your case `SUM` is overflowing. So you can comment on the line `Amount = a.Sum(a => a.Amount),` if it's not required.

So declare the `Amount` as `long` and caste it is `long` before assigning it to `Amount` like `Amount = a.Sum(a => (long)a.Amount`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @vivek nuna the problem is now solved:

Amount = a.Sum(a => (long)a.Amount)